# Cannot create partition on hard drive

Tags: partition, fdisk, gparted, parted, partition-table

I'm on PopOS 19.10, and I try to create a partition on my new SSD (Crucial MX500, 1TB).

Note that it worked on Windows, I could create a NTFS partition, so from this base I admit my SSD is healthy (can I ?).

First I tried from **GParted**, but it gives me a warning: `unrecognised disk label`. I have to create a partition table, what I do, but it seems to do nothing. Then I try to create a partition, which I can't do because I have to create the partition table before...

So with some search I tried to use **`fdisk /dev/sdc`**. I typed `n`, `p`, then keep default values. With `i` I got what I want, a partition:

```
Partition 1 sélectionnée
         Device: /dev/sdc1
          Start: 2048
            End: 1953525167
        Sectors: 1953523120
      Cylinders: 121602
           Size: 931,5G
             Id: 83
           Type: Linux
    Start-C/H/S: 0/32/33
      End-C/H/S: 769/80/63
```

So I leave with `w`. But no partition was created, when I return to `fdisk` it doesn't show me any partition.

Then I tried with **`parted`**:

```
(parted) unit GB                                                          
(parted) mklabel msdos                                                    
(parted) mkpart primary ext4 0 500                                        
(parted) print                                                            
Modèle: ATA CT1000MX500SSD1 (scsi)
Disque /dev/sdc : 1000GB
Taille des secteurs (logiques/physiques): 512B/4096B
Table de partitions : msdos
Disk Flags: 

Numéro  Début   Fin    Taille  Type     Système de fichiers  Fanions
 1      0,00GB  500GB  500GB   primary  ext4                 lba
```

But as with `fdisk` nothing is done. When I redo `parted`, then `print` I got this:

```
(parted) print                                                            
Erreur: Impossible d'ouvrir /dev/sdc - étiquette de disque non reconnue. (= unrecognized disk label)
Modèle: ATA CT1000MX500SSD1 (scsi)                                        
Disque /dev/sdc : 1000GB
Taille des secteurs (logiques/physiques): 512B/4096B
Table de partitions : unknown
Disk Flags:
```

I thought it may be a refresh issue, so I tried `partprobe /dev/sdc` without any change.
And of course restarted the computer.

I really don't know what to do...
Thank you for any help you could give !

Comment: Let's start by reviewing the MBR contents. Can you add the output of the command `head -c 512 < /dev/sdc | xxd -a"` - it will read the first 512 bytes from sdc, and dump it in hexadecimal format. One can then input that to `xxd -r > /tmp/mbr ; sfdisk -l /tmp/mbr` to view the contents of your MBR.

Comment: Hi, that's the output of the first command: https://pastebin.com/BuesYrQu The second doesn't show anything, it never ends it seems.

Comment: Sometimes it is not easy to reformat the disk, because various kernel tasks keep the MBR or existing partition. In that case, I start with a dd command to force erase some first block of the disk: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4096 count=64` (X=c folowing your example). After such erase you can take the disk off the machine, then connect it again and you can use your favorite method (gparted, fdisk, mkfs ...)

Comment: @schweik thanks, I tried your advice then reboot, but nothing changed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue. The fault was due to the SATA cable ! I just changed it and everything works fine now.

Thank you @Jonas Berlin @schweik for your helps !